# SQL Server : execute stored procedure and disconnect SSMS, how can I do that?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, ssms

I am using Azure SQL. I have a stored procedure. It does not returns any results. The stored procedure takes a long time to complete (4-5 hours).

My question is: I want to execute the stored procedure from Management Studio and let it run until it completes. While it is running, I want to disconnect Management Studio.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can create a job in SQL Agent, It don't need you open SSMS

Comment: @NolanShang azure do not provide SQL Agent feature

Comment: Here have two articles, wish they can give you some help.[1. How to work with the command line and Azure to automate tasks](http://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-work-with-the-command-line-and-azure-to-automate-tasks/).  [2. How to Schedule Azure SQL Database Stored Procedures](http://cotega.com/docs/sql_azure_scheduled_job)

Comment: @NolanShang this will definitely help

Comment: Also look into Elastic Jobs.  Getting started with Elastic Database jobs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-jobs-getting-started